# I'm not able to getting particular data from sqlite? Please help me

Tags: android

![This is my code for find method in DBHelper].class[1]

```
public StringBuilder findData(String find)
{    
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("Our data is:\n");
    Cursor c = ourHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT abbrevaition FROM        abbrtab WHERE acronym"+" =  ?  ;", new String[]{find});
    String remarks=" ";
    int iRemarks = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ABBR);
    if( c.moveToFirst() && c.getCount()>0 )
    {
        remarks= c.getString(iRemarks);
    if(remarks.isEmpty())
        {
            Toast.makeText(ourContext, "not", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    output.append(remarks); 
    }
    c.close();
    return output;
}
```

![This is code in Main.java for getting data from SQLite3. When i give the query select * from abbrtab then it execute. and apply  the where condition then i'm not get any thing. ][1]

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf("Hi"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ASNDBAdapter info = new ASNDBAdapter(AllBranches.this);
    info.open();
    String data = et.getText().toString();
    String result = info.findData(data).toString();
    Intent i = new Intent(AllBranches.this, ViewData.class);
    i.putExtra("my_data", result);
    startActivity(i);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(result),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    info.close();

}
```

Comment: Could it be that the field `abbrevaition` in your SELECT statement is misspelled?

Answer (score 2):

```
public StringBuilder findData(String find)
    {    
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("Our data is:\n");
        Cursor c = ourHelper.getReadableDatabase().query("abbrtab", new String[] {"abbrevaition"},"acronym" +"="+find, null, null, null, null);
        String remarks=" ";
        int iRemarks = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ABBR);
        if( c.moveToFirst() && c.getCount()>0 )
        {
            remarks= c.getString(iRemarks);
        if(remarks.isEmpty())
            {
                Toast.makeText(ourContext, "not", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        output.append(remarks); 
        }
        c.close();
        return output;
    }
```

Here "abbrtab" is table name and "abbrevaition" is name of field .

Answer (score 1):

To get a parameter's value into the query, you have to use a [parameter token](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam) like `?`:

```
String[] params = new String[]{ find };
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT abbrevaition FROM abbrtab WHERE acronym = ?",params);
```

For a simple query like this, you wouldn't need to use `rawQuery` but could just use [query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
String[] params = new String[]{ find };
Cursor c = db.query("abbrtab ", new String{"abbrevaition"},
                "acronym = ?", params,
                null, null, null);
```

You also have to ensure that your `Column Names` are correct.

try this way.